# Compute the logarithm of a matrix

Tags: code-golf, math, matrix

There have already been challenges about computing the [exponential](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230784/to-raise-e-to-the-power-of-a-matrix) of a matrix , as well as computing the [natural logarithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/262711/vanilla-natural-logarithm-challenge)
of a number. This challenge is about finding the (natural) logarithm of matrix.

You task is to write a program of function that takes an invertible \$n \times n\$ matrix \$A\$ as input and returns the [matrix logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix) of that matrix.
The matrix logarithm of a matrix \$ A\$ is defined (similar to the real logarithm) to be a matrix \$L\$ with \$ exp(L) = A\$.

Like the complex logarithm the matrix logarithm is not unique, you can choose to return any of the possible results for a given matrix.

Examples (rounded to five significant digits):

```
log( [[ 1,0],[0, 1]] ) = [[0,0], [0,0]]
log( [[ 1,2],[3, 4]] ) = [[-0.3504 + 2.3911i, 0.9294 - 1.0938i], [1.3940 - 1.6406i, 1.04359 + 0.75047i]]
log( [[-1,0],[0,-1]] ) = [[0,pi],[-pi,0]] // exact
log( [[-1,0],[0,-1]] ) = [[0,-pi],[pi,0]] // also exact
log( [[-1,0],[0,-1]] ) = [[pi*i,0],[0,pi*i]] // also exact

log( [[-1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,2]] ) = [[3.1416i, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0.69315]]
log( [[1,2,3],[4,5,4],[3,2,1]] ) = [[0.6032 + 1.5708i, 0.71969, -0.0900 - 1.5708i],[1.4394, 0.87307, 1.4394],[-0.0900 - 1.5708i, 0.71969, 0.6032 + 1.5708i]]
```

If you want to try out more examples use the function `digits 5 matrix logarithm` followed by a matrix in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com)

Rules:

- You can Input/Output matrices as nested lists
- You can Input/Output complex numbers as pairs of real numbers
- You can assume the logarithm of the input matrix exists
- Your result should be accurate up to at least 5 significant (decimal) digits
- You only have to handle matrices of sizes \$2\times2\$ and \$3\times3\$
- You program may return different results when called multiple times on the same input as long as all of them are correct
- Please add builtin answers (including libraries) to the community wiki instead of posting them separately
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) the shortest solution (per language) wins

Answer (score 3):

## Python + scipy, 30 bytes

```py
from scipy.linalg import*
logm
```

Comment: Should this count as builtin?

Comment: @l4m2 Yes. But it was posted before I added the rule against built-in solutions.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 61 bytes

```r
function(m,e=eigen(m))e$ve%*%diag(log(e$va+0i))%*%solve(e$ve)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDRbsMgDEXf9xWWtkqwEmoHEsJDPiZLWYXUJtXWVfv7zNAtmpI8Ab724fp@TOfxdGmn96@hv8VxEBcV2hBPgW9Shpd72L3ujrE7Ce4T/O72GKXk4ud4vodUCTIzBPRvcTiKXgAplKoXqICkBAnP0M4iJg3yIZ9Wc2WaMwrsaq5AbSq0sIdSG08UFaD2pbdQAGn0pomJSyxazLXaYs1dLFpTeR5E7Zjg4urjYjZcbBm@xiQW15g8w@EA4bvrbxuMP8qMQ15oyTOaLCVjHM9vFMurrr2hamWT41Emga2qlH0kVaoNx7pGU/LCpCuHTU7Kka@9Ak4RPT7yyVqikLYcWupqnEGXIkuFvPSy/x9r@Q37nX4A)

Uses [this method from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Calculating_the_logarithm_of_a_diagonalizable_matrix) for finding the logarithm of a diagonalizable (and so invertible) matrix.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 105 bytes*

**(*)Only for matrices `M` for which `norm(M-I)<1`**

```r
function(m,i=diag(nrow(m)),R=Reduce)R(`+`,lapply(1:1e3,function(n)-(-1)^n*R(`%*%`,rep(list(m-i),n),i)/n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY3BCoMwEETv/YpAEXbtSg29CfkJP6CoMZWFZJU0tvTrrXrwUuhlBmbmMXHx4xDM8pjFJh4FArHpuR1A4viGgEi1qV0/W4c1NJeGfDtN/gO60u5GByZYQKHxLvm6yvKsoegm8PxMEApGEiTGqyDuf6Bsx9KDBaWpRLJQktKICtVZmaMst07thqcfTv/h9MGtsYzJVZsqlpeLiTvvli8)

I didn't initially spot the 'invertible' in the challenge specification, so tried to use [this other method from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Power_series_expression) which works for non-diagonalizable matrices `M`, but with the restriction that `norm(M-I)` must be `<1`.
In many cases, this can be extended to matrices with larger-valued elements, using `L ==  log( M %*% X) == log( M ) + log( X )`: in these cases, we divide the matrix `M` by a sufficiently-large power-of-2 `l`, and add `l` times the log of 2x the identity matrix to the result.
Nevertheless, this is not fully-general, and fails for matrices `M` that cannot be scaled to satisfy `norm(M-I)<1` (for instance, the matrix `[[1,2],[3,4]]`).

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 158 bytes*

**(*)Only for matrices `M` for which `norm(M*l-I)<1` for some value `l`**

```r
function(m,i=diag(nrow(m)),l=log2(norm(m)*2)%/%1,f=function(m,R=Reduce)R(`+`,lapply(1:1e3,function(n)-(-1)^n*R(`%*%`,rep(list(m-i),n),i)/n)))f(m/2^l)+l*f(i*2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY5dasMwEITfewpBMew6K1k/ppSALuEDBCeOHASSbFynpad3ZdOGkrwU@rLLsjPfzLSE4RLt0l9TN/shQSRvz/54gTQNHxARKdgs0ZCGKea71FhUhaLe/rI0tnHna@ewgXbXUjiOY/gEtVfO0E2WkANXeEhlVhVl0dLkRgj@bYbIPVJC8lglROwhVvoQcBfKHnxO3EoC604@naEDpkgidSCJKUSG7JnZ21OuP7YtfLr3SdI/TiMfrFoYSUqob4AR9aqxLA2z26@T@fTuptmfgrtHa6pXsCZWP3C5EVJRLV43sM5Y4lK8qD/Dc2@uZWXWBG5klVPU/@ovXw)

Answer (score 2):

## Scala + [jeigen](https://github.com/hughperkins/jeigen/), 22 bytes

```scala
import jeigen.*
_.mlog
```

[Try it online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/70XxNAAWSf6aYo50FWW89w)

Answer (score 2):

## Built-in solutions

### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 9 bytes

```
MatrixLog
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zexpCizwic//X9AUWZeSXRatEJ1ta6hjoIBENXqKFQDaUMEE4iMamsVYmP/AwA)

### [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 4 bytes

```
logm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9m66Cnp/c/Jz8993@aRrShgoG1goGCYawmF5hnZK1grGAC4elCJXUNEXyocghloGAE16dgbK1gomCqYAIywAhk4H8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 29 bytes

```matlab
@(a)(a^1e-9-eye(size(a)))*1e9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI1FTIzHOMFXXUje1MlWjOLMqFSikqallmGr5Pyc/PVcj2lDBwFrBQMEwVpMrDYUHkzayVjBWMIFJw3kQaV2oBl2ofhQ@QgnUVAhloGCEUIxFBm6xgrG1gomCqYIJyE4jhBOxSPwHAA)

Based on [@Jos Woolley's Excel answer to the Vanilla Natural Logarithm Challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/262714/9288).